# R: Data-cleaning dataframe that exceeds 2 standard derivations from mean

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I simply don't know how to do it, and my coding experience is very limited. I have 90 reaction times per subject and some of the trial times are too high (because of lacking motivation or attention). How can I extract subject data that is too high (not in comparison to other subjects, in comparison to the subjects own mean and SD).

```
print(d1$(Reaction.time < mean+2*SD))
```

as you can see I have no clue what I'm doing, but eh, I'm trying

d1 is the dataframe containing the data of one particular subject.
Reaction.time is one column of the dataframe containing (duh) all the reaction times of that subject.

mean (mean reaction time) is a column that I added via mutate(and so on) and SD is the standard deviation of that subject that I added via mutate(and so on) as well. SD and mean can be seen in the dataframe. But how can I take out (/or only print the others) all the rows containing reaction times that are above 2 SD from mean and also all rows that are below 2 SD from Mean.

Comment: try `filter(df, Reaction.time < (mean+2*SD))`

Comment: Or replace @AndS.'s `filter` with `subset` for the base-R equivalent (i.e., if you aren't currently using `dplyr`). Note that `d1$(...)` is not valid R syntax, and `print`ing something is not the same as extracting, filtering, reducing, or transforming it. My guess is that `d1 <- subset(...)` or `d1 <- filter(...)` (as suggested above) will do the trick for you.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: AndS. filter() works!
Syntaxwise, how do I make r filter both ways, so 2 standard derivations above the mean and below it? I couldnt make it work and if I just copy paste filter(df, Reaction.time > (mean-2*SD)) below it, it doesnt work anymore, idk why